# How to load existing WinSCP sessions into PuTTY sessions?

Tags: putty, export, import, winscp, configuration-managment

I would like to export all my existing WinSCP sessions (stored in `winscp.ini`) to PuTTY.

I know about the integration of both WinSCP and PuTTY. And it is working fine for me. But I would like to use PuTTY sometimes without opening WinSCP.

I have 100+ WinSCP sessions that I want to export to PuTTY. How would I go about it?

Answer (score 2):

For Winscp you can export the settings from winscp to a configfile:

> To export/back up your configuration, go to Tools > Export/Backup
>   configuration on Login dialog.

For Putty you can export the Registry to save the sessions and export to another PC

> Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SimonTatham\PuTTY\

But to Convert from winscp to putty or the other direction you need a converter,
i use the [PuttySessionConverter](https://empirius.de/de/about/blog/2014/12/16/putty-session-manager-tool/)

But i think there is no need to export to putty, you can use winscp as SessionManager
mark a Session in WinScp and press CTRL+P and winscp open Putty.

Comment: "But i think there is no need to export to putty, you can use winscp as SessionManager mark a Session in WinScp and press CTRL+P and winscp open Putty." -  Excellent tip.

Comment: The link to the converter tool is broken.

Answer (score 1):

As @SavGuard already answered, you can actually [use WinSCP as a better session manager for PuTTY](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_winscp_as_putty_session_manager).

There's no additional work comparing to opening the session in PuTTY directly. You can [open PuTTY straight from WinSCP Login dialog](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_login#opening_in_putty). You do not have to open the session in WinSCP first.

---

But to answer your literal question: WinSCP uses a very similar storage format for saving the sites as PuTTY does.

So if you export the WinSCP registry key:

```ini
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Martin Prikryl\WinSCP 2\Sessions]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Martin Prikryl\WinSCP 2\Sessions\MySession]
"HostName"="example.com"
"UserName"="username"
```

And replace `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Martin Prikryl\WinSCP 2\Sessions` with `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SimonTatham\PuTTY\Sessions`, and import back, it should more or less work (though not all settings will import correctly).

As you currently use an INI file with WinSCP, you will first have to [switch to registry storage](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_pref_storage).

Comment: This doesn't work well because the `PublicKeyFile` value is encoded differently.

Comment: @Wolf Yes, that's why my answer says *"very similar storage format"* and *"should more or less work"*.